# Help with Validation Rule for record block

Tags: formula, validation-rule

```
AND( NOT(Star_Job_Project__c ='Technology Product Sales'))
```

This validation rule is on Time Entry Object in which if `STAR Job` API - `Star_Job_Project__c` is equal to Technology Product Sales then that particular record will block.

My issue is the above validation rule is working in every record I only want for specific condition.

User can edit if star job is equal to any other value but if the value is Technology Product Sales the record should block.

Can anyone help in the above validation?

Comment: If you want the validation to only fail when Its value is Technology Product Sales you should take out the NOT () from the validation rule formula. 

Also the AND isn't doing anything at all so your validation rule could be Star_job_project__c = 'Technology Product Sales'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You write validation rules that **prevent** record from being created. Write conditions that prevent. So if your condition is `true` - record creation would be stopped. In your current condition

```
AND( NOT(Star_Job_Project__c ='Technology Product Sales'))
```

record creation will be stopped if `Star_Job_Project__c` **not equals to**  'Technology Product Sales'

so according to your requirement correct formula is

```
Star_Job_Project__r.Name ='Technology Product Sales'
```

Comment: Star_Job_Project__c ='Technology Product Sales'

This validation rule is not working as per my requirement.

According to my requirement when Star JOB is equal to "Technology Product Sales" no one can go and edit the records so need to write a validation rule if someone click edit and change the record it shows an error message.

with above validation rule i am able to edit and make changes and then save the records.

Comment: If i use this,

Star_Job_Project__c ='Technology Product Sales'

And to test this is opened the record with the above condition and make changes and save the record then i am able to save the record.

Again my requirement is to prevent users to edit the record if Star_Job_Project__c ='Technology Product Sales' will met the criteria.

So the record should block.

Comment: @Ravina what type of field is `Star_Job_Project__c` ?

Comment: @ Oleksandr Field Name - Star Job
API Name -Star_Job_Project__c

Lookup field on Project .

Comment: lookup field on Project object

Comment: @Ravina that matters ! I have updated answer for case, when Star_Job_Project__c is **Lookup**